# Recognizing small numbers through a For Each loop in VBA

Tags: vba, loops, for-loop, numbers, each

I have the following piece of code:

```
Range("C13:Y21").Select
For Each cell2 In Selection
      If cell2 = "-0.0568" Then
            x = 1000
      End If`
Next cell2
```

I want to discover the value -0.0568, but the issue I have is that when the value comes up, Visual Basic sees it as being equal to 0. I obviously want Visual Basic to see the value for what it actually is and not rounded. Could someone spot the mistake I'm making?

Comment: what if you check it this way: `If cell2 = -0.0568 then`?

Comment: Nope, I tried it previously.

Comment: What makes you think it sees that value as zero? Should work fine (without the quotes as KazJaw suggests)

Comment: what results you get if you check in immediate windows the following properties (select your cell with -0.0568 before): `? Acttivecell.value` and `? Acttivecell.value2` and `? Acttivecell.text`

Answer (score 1):

Your problem comes from data types. This runs perfectly on my computer with just this code. I suspect you have declared cell2 as a datatype that isn't fit.

I like this way better though:

```
Sub Test()


Range("C13:C21").Select
For Each cell2 In Selection
      If cell2.Value = -0.0568 Then
            Debug.Print "YES"
      End If
Next cell2


End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

If you click in the cell(s) with the value -0.0568 are there any extra decimals showing in the formula bar?

You could consider checking both Value and Text, to account for this:

```
  If cell2.Value = -0.0568 Or cell2.Text = "-0.0568" Then
```

where `.Text` is the displayed value in the cell.

To avoid any issues when comparing numbers with decimals you could consider using `Round()`:

```
  If Round(cell2.Value, 4) = -0.0568 Then
```